# Running HMA VPN on remote server

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to setup HMA VPN my remote server on Amazon EC2 machine (Ubunutu 12.04.02), so that the ip of the outgoing traffic changes.

But as soon as the HMA script start vpn connection, SSH connection from my local machine to the server gets lost.

I think the problem lies with VPN client locking the network adapter so that SSH server is no longer able to listen to the same port as it was listening to earlier.

Please suggest what might be causing this problem?